# why multi language swiftUI app not working

Tags: swiftui, localization

I want to create a multi language app in swiftUI, I created the zh-Hans.lproj and en.lproj folder, and created Localizable.string file under each folder, entered the key and value string on the each string file, and changed the app to the Chinese simplified language, but I am not sure why the it is not working, it does not show the text as Chinese but still in English

[image: Chinese Localizable.string file]

[image: contentView use "setting" as a key]

[image: simulator show English]

Comment: you could try setting: `ContentView().environment(\.locale, Locale(identifier: "zh-Hans"))`
  in your `@main struct TestApp:....`.

Comment: Normally you should create the Localizable.strings file and the with file inspector add the new languages.

Answer (score 0):

your second screenshot looks kind of weird. If you want to support several languages, you only need to add one Localizable.strings file to your project. Then, go to the settings of your project by clicking on the blue icon of your project. Inside of this menu you will find your Locations and you will be able to add as many languages as you want to. After that, as @Ptit Xav says, after clicking on the Localizable.strings file you created before, go to the File Inspector and in the Location section you will see a button called Localise. Click on it and this will link this file to your one  of your languages. Then, click on all the checkboxes that appears where the localise button used to be.